# Can't mount an .iso file

Tags: mount, iso

I'm trying to mount an iso. file. To do that I have already create a directory to serve as the mount location; I wrote in the terminal "sudo mkdir /media/iso" to do this.

But the moment I try to moiunt the iso. in the target directory by using "sudo mount -o loop path/to/iso/file/my_iso_file.iso /media/iso" the following mistake pops up:

**mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop3,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail or so.**

Looking up a bit on this whole thing I came up with the possibility that the ISO is not in 9660 format and that I should convert it.

Thing is that I don't know how to do that and even if I could I would like to know first if I should.

I tried the *file* command to know the format of the "iso" this way:

"$ file /path/to/iso/file/my_iso_file.iso"

but the only thing that came up is

"/path/to/iso/file/my_iso_file.iso: data".

Please help.

Could someone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What iso ? Hard to tell from what you posted, but it seems the .iso is either corrupt or not an iso.

Comment: Use `sudo mount -t iso9660  /path/to/iso/file/my_iso_file.iso /media/iso`, but first verify the checksum of `my_iso_file.data`, or download it again and compare the two versions.